# Hash as index storing as varbinary or nvarchar in sql server

Tags: sql-server, hash, primary-key, clustered-index

there is a task implementing a table with HASH value as primary key.

Currently the designer proposes a varbinary(32) to store a 16 byte length MD5 hash.
So he stores 16 bytes of information in 64 byte of storage. Isnt't that a waste?

is there any advantage or disadvantage of storing a primary key hash as nvarchar vs varbinary?

In my opinion varbinary should be more efficient for joins and also varbinary shoud lead to less page splits ?

I need a second opinion on this matter!

Comment: md5 will generate collisions for every few million rows or so,AFAIK

Comment: i know but this is not the question. it is about performance issues when storing as varbinary or nvarchar